# memory exhausted error in magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

Hi I have around **25000** **products** in my Magento store, I need to increase the price by 25% for all the products , I have written a script for this , but when i am running that i am getting memory exhausted error. I have tried to increase it in the .**htacess** file but **still** its **not** working please suggest me how can to do this.

below is my cod

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
     ;
 foreach ($products as $product) {
     $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() * 1.25);
     $product->save();
 }
```

Comment: for a 25% increase shouldn't that be 1.25 instead of 1.03

Comment: Can you post the specific error message so we can see what your current memory limit is? You may need to rework this so that you're not grabbing all products at once, but if your memory limit is pretty low, then you may just need to jump it up for this one-off script (also make sure that your htaccess file is actually allowed to set your memory limit - many hosts forbid changing the available memory if you're in a shared environment)... lastly: what Orangepill said.

Comment: increase the memory from the php script it self. `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`

Comment: Scripts operate off the command line (cli) interpreter and usually have a completely different php.ini file with its own memory_limit set. As @DevZer0 shows you, this can be set within the script, or it can, if you have control of the server, be set in the master cli php.ini file.

Comment: is this being run from a stand alone script? can you put the full code please.. and also the exact error.

Comment: Sorry but what is the problem to run a query directly over the database?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just export product with price.
Modify sheet and then import.